# VBA: reading date from a string of a specific format

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to convert strings to Date data type in VBA. I can use **CDate()** function for this purpose, but it uses its own implicit algorithm for parsing strings and I would like to specify my own format to differentiate between  "DD/MM/YY" and "MM/DD/YY", for example.

Please notice that unlike Visual Basic, VBA has no **DateTime.TryParseExact** function.

**ADD**: As some answers suggest, I can write my own parser. If there is no built-in solution, it will be my choice.

Comment: Assuming you mean `CVDate()` you dont get more options.

Comment: can you post the format of your strings

Comment: @braX, Microsoft: CVDate is identical to CDate except for the declared type of its return value. I use CDate to get Date variable.

Comment: @GowthamShiva Let's say my string is "01/02/2017". I want to tell VBA what it is ("DD/MM/YYYY" or "MM/DD/YYYY") explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this...

```
strDate = Split(strDate,"/")
newstrDate = strDate(1) & "/" & strDate(0) & "/" & strDate(2)
strDate = CDate(newstrDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would avoid CDate alltogether and instead split the date string into year, month and day and use DateSerial(year, month, day). This way you have full control.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the below code

```
Msgbox Format("24/01/2017","MMM, DD, YYYY")
```

This will give you output as `Jan, 24, 2017` . You can use other format which is easily available when you click on the Format cells. Thanks

Comment: Wrong way round. Read the question again.

Comment: I suppose that this will first convert "24/01/2017" to Date data type and then format it using "MMM, DD, YYYY". I want to control the first stage so that I can specify that "01/02/2017" is February, 1 and not January, 2 (or other way round).